# Why Database.Batchable has to be of Type SObject? Can't we specify a Specific Type for which we are writing Batch Class?

Tags: apex, batch

Whenever i see an example of Batch Class I see Following class Declaration

`class DebugDeleteBatch implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>{}`

Question i have here is that why can't we use something like below

`class DebugDeleteBatch implements Database.Batchable<Account>{}`

Answer (score 1):

The restriction you mentioned is enforced only when the start method returns an QueryLocator (vs. Iterable). When it returns a QueryLocator, it must be stated as implements Database.Batchable because a QueryLocator uses dynamic SOQL and returns objects without knowing their type ahead of runtime.

However this doesn't limit you in anything. The execute method signature can be defined with the type you're actually expecting to get. E.g. execute(BatchableContext bc, List scope){}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom iterator class if you want an SObject specific batch. Please refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm) on how to create one.

```
  public class Database {
  public static void executeBatch(Database.Batchable batch) {
    executeBatch(batch, 200);
  }
  public static void executeBatch(Database.Batchable batch, Integer limit) {
    Database.BatchableContext BC = new Database.BatchableContext();
    Database.Iterator iterator = batch.start(BC);
    List<Object> items = new List<Object>();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
      items.add(iterator.next());
      if(items.size()==limit) {
        batch.execute(BC,items);
        items.clear();
      }
    }
    batch.finish(BC);
  }
}
```